# Mongodb aggregation / map reduce values from many collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have about 30 milions of documents like:

```
{
 "_id" : {
    "municipality" : "Stockholm",
    "keyword" : "hotel"
},
"total" : 2
}
```

in 12 monthly based collections. Now I need to sum up those values to collection from whole year. There are a lot of examples how to do aggregation in one collection, but I'm not sure how to start with it for many of them. Should I begin with some mapreduce emit function?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you could probably use the [**`db.getCollectionNames()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionNames/) command to get an array of collection names that you can then iterate over in a loop, calculate the aggregation of each collection using the [**`db.getCollection(name)`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getCollection/#db.getCollection) method.

To illustrate this, suppose in your test database you have the following collections and the respective documents:

```
use test;
db.jan_stats.insert([
    {
         "_id" : {
            "municipality" : "Stockholm",
            "keyword" : "hotel"
        },
        "total" : 2
    },
    {
         "_id" : {
            "municipality" : "Malmö",
            "keyword" : "school"
        },
        "total" : 5
    }
]);
db.feb_stats.insert([
    {
         "_id" : {
            "municipality" : "Stockholm",
            "keyword" : "hotel"
        },
        "total" : 6
    },
    {
         "_id" : {
            "municipality" : "Malmö",
            "keyword" : "school"
        },
        "total" : 4
    }
]);
```

You can then try the logic above in mongo shell as follows:

```
connecting to: test
> var collections = db.getCollectionNames(),
...     annual_total = 0;
> collections.forEach(function(name){
...     var res = db.getCollection(name).aggregate([
...         {
...             "$group": {
...                 "_id": null,
...                 "total": { "$sum": "$total" }
...             }
...         }
...     ]).toArray();
...     annual_total += res[0].total;
... });
> print(annual_total);
17
>
```

The above will of course give you the correct annual total if the actual number of collections were 12 i.e for each month.

Performance-wise you would then need to do the appropriate optimization so that the above aggregation works faster. Not so sure about how that compares with the Map-Reduce operation but I believe if you are only aggregating on the total field then using the **[appropriate indexing](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes)** and **[reshaping the pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#aggregation-pipeline-optimization)** for improved performance, the aggregation method would be relatively faster.